# folium.plugins.MeasureControl is not working

Tags: python, folium

when i copy this code on jupyter:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MeasureControl

m = folium.Map([-27.5717, -48.6256], zoom_start=10)

m.add_child(MeasureControl())
```

(https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/plugins/measure_control.html)

does not work, i can't make two clicks, and when i do in my project is the same

> my version of folium is 0.14.0
>
> my python version is 3.9.13

Comment: Please edit your question and provide
[a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
, along with your desired
 results, your actual
 results, including all errors
, and demonstrate your research and your attempts
 and explain what precisely didn’t work.